# How can one disable the first autoselect in a VS datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, datasource

I have created an application in Visual Studio (C#) that makes use of a datagridview. Now, when I assign the DataSource of that datagridview, it automatically selects the first row, and executes my code for selection. Since I frequently reassign that datasource, this is not desireable. Is there any way to change it so it doesn't automatically make that first select, and only relies on the user's selections?

Thanks!

In response to the comment of Darshan Joshi:
Apart from the auto-generated code, the only thing altered on the datagridview is setting AutoGenerateColumns to false, and setting the DataSource property.
I've placed a MessageBox.Show in my selectionchanged delegate, and it seems it even gets called thrice every time the datasource is set. Once just before the data is loaded, and twice after.

I can't set selected to false on load, since the datasource is set after certain user actions, not on initialization.

Comment: It`s strange behavior, It must not select value automatically, can you show your code, it might help to grasp what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is my solution.

The tricky part was finding where to clear the selection... We can only clear the selection after the selection has been set by the DataGridView. At first the selection is only ready to be cleared in the Form.Load event, but subsiquent settings of the DataGridView.DataSource the selection is ready to be cleared straight after the DataSource assignment.

```
public class DataGridView_AutoSelectSuppressed : DataGridView
{
    private bool SuppressAutoSelection { get; set; }

    public DataGridView_AutoSelectSuppressed() : base()
    {
        SuppressAutoSelection = true;
    }

    public new /*shadowing*/ object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return base.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            SuppressAutoSelection = true;
            Form parent = this.FindForm();

            // Either the selection gets cleared on form load....
            parent.Load -= parent_Load;
            parent.Load += parent_Load;

            base.DataSource = value;

            // ...or it gets cleared straight after the DataSource is set
            ClearSelectionAndResetSuppression();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SuppressAutoSelection)
            return;

        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }

    private void ClearSelectionAndResetSuppression()
    {
        if (this.SelectedRows.Count > 0 || this.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            this.ClearSelection();
            SuppressAutoSelection = false;
        }
    }

    private void parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearSelectionAndResetSuppression();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Heh heh to be completely honest my friend I already quit my job by now so in theory it does not help :P But still, very interesting, thank you. It is very weird that something so seemingly simple needs a solution so unwieldy. One of the reasons I do not like coding in C# - Too much going on behind the scenes of which you have no immediate control over. Though again, thanks for the response, maybe this will help other unfortunate souls in the future!

Comment: @Pino lol!! awesome, have a good one mate. Solutions round undesired behavior in things like DataGridViews seems to take too much effort, I'm always hoping for a more elegant solution. Sometimes it feels like I'm working with a Heath Robinson machine, but then used in the way they expect to be used the performance can be excellent.

Comment: I tried your solution, though it didn't seem to actually work.

Comment: @leetNightshade very sorry the solution didn't work for you. I tried it just now with a new WinForm project both .Net3.5 and .Net4 which worked ok but if I may ask what type of malfunction was there? Was it just still selecting the first row?, or was it throwing an exception or something?

Comment: @user2433394 The first row was is still being selected, yes.  Though I found an alternative solution for my problem that worked out well.  I just saved the selection before I modify the list, and if the selection does not match the old selection, I revert it back to what it was.  So this solution works when you have a single place that data is being added, so you can do a setup before it's added to handle the auto selection.  Yours would be a little more ideal, intercepting it at the source.

Comment: @leetNightshade nice one for your solution. I'm wondering if my mistake is presuming when the data binding has finished. If there's asynchronicity then it might be best to /also/ call `ClearSelectionAndResetSuppression()` off the `DataBindingComplete` event.

Comment: @user2433394 Wait, so in my test case the first data is added after the dataSource has been bound, and that's when the auto selection happens.  Yours only handles it when the dataSource is bound/rebound, right?  I don't rebind the dataSource, I add data directly to it and the changes are reflected in the dataGridView I'm using.

Comment: @leetNightshade yes binding and rebinding was my situation :)

Answer (score 9):

You should call: ClearSelection after event: DataBindingComplete

Comment: This would be the ideal solution but it doesn't suppress SelectionChanged event which is still triggered for the 'phantom' selection

Comment: If you're not using data binding then call ClearSelection the first time the dataGrid becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can deselect it in your form_load event 
like

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = false;
        }
```

Comment: This might fix the symptom, it doesn't address the underlying problem

Comment: To address as to why I did not choose this answer: It does not fix the symptom if the datasource is set after user interaction instead of form loading.

Answer (score 0):

To load the grid without any selection, you can use this code snippet.

```
 GridView.CurrentCell = null;
```

This will load it plain, without any selection. Add this after assigning data-source to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are **NOT** calling the method to load the data from the form constructor. If you call it from the Form.load()

also after the myDataGridView is loaded do this

myDataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = false;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Deregister the SelectionChanged event just before binding the data and then re-register the event.
Maybe you should delete the registration of the event in the designer and register the event manually in your code.

`myDGV.SelectionChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.myDGV_SelectionChanged);`

Answer (score 0):

Your experience may vary, but in my work I frequently fight this when the grid first loads, and although many solutions have been found to be acceptable (and far more are just ludicrous), they don't all work in every scenario. The one solution I find that works the most (for me, again your experience and scenarios may vary) is handling DataGridView.VisibleChanged:

```
    public ThingWithGrid() {
        Grid.VisibleChanged += Grid_VisibleChanged;
    }

    private void Grid_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateSelectedRows(InitialSelection);
        Grid.VisibleChanged -= Grid_VisibleChanged;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to remove the eventhandler, assign the new datasource, clear the selection and reassign the eventhandler:

```
private void updateDataGridViewDataSource(%whatevertype% %whatever%) {
    dataGridView1.SelectionChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = %whatever%
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, a more simple solution was enough, in my `DataGridView_DataBindingComplete` handler:

```
DataGridView.ClearSelection();
if (DataGridView.Focused)
    DataGridView.DataBindingComplete -= DataGridView_DataBindingComplete;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add SelectedItem="-1", this will do the trick

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" SelectedItem="-1" />
```

Comment: It's not tagged, but the question is a WinForms issue.